# How to Elasticsearch entities not created using API (jhipster)

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

Using Jhipster with Postgresql, I have created an entity "Customer". When I add data to this entity using the Angular UI or POST to the API, I can search this data using the search form on the UI.

However, when I insert data in the database directly, the data is not searchable even after application restart. The search would still work (only) on the data added through the UI.

I am new to elasticsearch and do not know if there is a missing step between inserting data on the backend and making it available to elasticsearch. Please help, if there is something I need to configure to let elasticsearch pick up data from the database during application startup.

My application-dev.yml excerpt for spring data elasticsearch:

```
    data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name:
        cluster-nodes:
        properties:
            path:
              logs: target/elasticsearch/log
              data: target/elasticsearch/data
```

Comment: Please explain all you've done to configure Elasticsearch with JHipster. How does your `application.yml` file look like?

Comment: @Val, I have not changed any configuration in the application.yml related to search. I have added the elasticsearch properties in the yml file in the original question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch is essentially a datastore which is why JHipster saves to the search repositories at the same time as the regular JPA repositories. There is no built-in reindexing functionality for making changes to it outside of the API.

I have written a module that will generate a service for reindexing all entities.

https://github.com/geraldhumphries/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer

Comment: Indeed this is the case. A simple workaround I used for my use case was to use the repository to pull the objects in the database and save them to the search repository. Added what I did in a separate comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the service generated by my module does. I coded it for my own project and decided to create it as a module after seeing this question. Open an issue if you have any suggestions.

Comment: something like List<Customer> custs = customerRepository.findAll(); and then for each cust, customerSearchRepository.save(cust).